# how to add to query parameter if value is not null in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am add query string like this:

```
reportQuery: function (params) {
    var that = this;
    var queryData = {
      "patient_id": params.exampleNo,
      "hospital_name": params.hospitalName,
      "item_name": params.checkItem,
      "report_date": params.reportDate
    };
    API.executeGet(queryData, function (res) {
      if (res.data.Data && res.data.Data.length > 0) {
        that.setData({
          reportList: res.data.Data,
          containsData: true
        });
      }
    }, '/api/Analysis/Search', 'post');
  }
```

but sometimes the `params.exampleNo` or `params.checkItem` is null or undefined. What is the clean write way to add the value to query if it is not null? For example, if `params.checkItem` is null, my query should look like this:

```
       var queryData = {
          "patient_id": params.exampleNo,
          "hospital_name": params.hospitalName,
          "report_date": params.reportDate
        };
```

when It is null, just ignore it. If write like this:

```
if(value){
   var queryData ={
   }
}
```

It is ugly.

Comment: `Object.keys(params).reduce((a,c) => params[c] ? {...a, [c]: params[c] } : a, {})`

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think you need some sort of map to link the `params` keys with the `queryData` keys as they are different. Please check the second snippet below and let me know if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just have a guard clause at the top of the function that will return from the function if `params === null`, like:

```js
function(params) {
  if (params === null) return;

  var that = this;
  var queryData = {
    "patient_id": params.exampleNo,
    "hospital_name": params.hospitalName,
    "item_name": params.checkItem,
    "report_date": params.reportDate
  };

  API.executeGet(queryData, function(res) {
    if (res.data.Data && res.data.Data.length > 0) {
      that.setData({
        reportList: res.data.Data,
        containsData: true
      });
    }
  }, '/api/Analysis/Search', 'post');
}
```

If you want to check if some value in `params` is falsy (`null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, empty string (`""`), `false` or `0`), then you can do something like:

```js
params = {
  exampleNo: 42,
  hospitalName: 'Gotham General Hospital',
  checkItem: null,
  reportDate: "01/01/1970",
};

let map = {
  exampleNo: "patient_id",
  hospitalName: "hospital_name",
  checkItem: "item_name",
  reportDate: "report_date",
};

let query = Object.entries(params).reduce((p, [k, v]) => {
  if (v) p[map[k]] = v;
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(query);

// {
//   "patient_id": 42,
//   "hospital_name": "Gotham General Hospital",
//   "report_date": "01/01/1970"
// }
```

Comment: if the params contained value is null,how to handle property.

Comment: So you want to return in case any property of `params` is null or undefined? In that case you'll have to loop through them and check if any is null/undefined and return. The code above only works for the `null` case, if you want for `undefined` as well you can do `if (!params) return;`

Answer (score 1):

```
let params = {
  exampleNo: null,
  hospitalName: undefined,
  checkItem: true,
  reportDate: "42",
};
let newObj = {};
Object.keys(params).forEach((item) =>{
    if(params[item]){ newObj[item] = params[item]}
} );
console.log('get newbj', newObj);
```

You can pass newObj as your queryData.

Comment: The `queryData` keys are different from the `params` keys.